# insert multiple row on a single column with duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

TOtally newbie here. I have a problem about insert syntax. I want my table to look like this with ID as primary key(AI, NN,) and I can input multiple items on document with the same case and name. I am currently using a php script that extracts those info from a result to insert them into the database but have problem regarding the syntax.

```
   ID|    Case|  Name| Document| Date
 ----------------------------------------------
   1     233    alex    ITR      2015-1-1
   2     233    alex    ITR      2015-1-1
   3     233    alex    NULL     0000-0-0
   4     234    ben     COC      2015-3-3
   5     234    ben     VAT      2015-3-3
   6     234    ben     NULL     0000-0-0
```

my code is something like this:

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO table1 (Case, Name, Document, Date) VALUES ('$casenum','$name','$doc1-5(*this is where I dont know what todo)','$date1-5(this also)
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Can you please copy us your error message? Plus, where is the table name?

Comment: I want to make a syntax like that in a single $sql code can't figure out how also the "Document" column takes 3-5 variables( $doc1,$oc2,$doc3) same as "Date" column takes 3-5 variables($doc1_date....n)

Comment: Stop what you're doing and use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar.  What you have right now is wide open to SQL injection attacks and will also just stop working randomly when reserved characters get used.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have specific list of documents and dates, can't you just use an array?

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$docs =('ITR', 'COC', etc);
$date =('2015-1-1', etc);

// prepare and bind    
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO table1 (Case, Name, Document, Date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $casenum, $name, $docs[0-4], $date[0-4]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$conn->commit(); //otherwise your data won't save
```

Also make sure to use prepare and bind_param all the time in order to prevent sql injection - crucially important or your whole db can get messed up

Comment: Please don't post code that you know to be insecure.  There are people that copy/paste from StackOverflow without reading all the time.  Can you give an example with a parameterized query instead?

Comment: the problem is I don't have a specific list of doc, it depends on a client.

Comment: Then all you have to do is make a variable $doc, get that value from a client, and set it as $doc! ($docs = "whatever client gives you")

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add multiple values in one sql statement, you can catenate them at the end:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (Case, Name, Document, Date) VALUES (233, 'alex', 'ITR', '2015-1-1') , (233, 'alex', 'NULL', 0000-0-0) , …
```

If you have a `$values` array like this one:

```
Array (
    Array (
        [Case] => 233,
        [Name] => 'alex',
        [Document] => 'ITR',
        [Date] => '2015-1-1'
    ),
    …
)
```

You can consider doing something like that:

```
$values = // def you array here
$texts = array_map( function($value) { return "({$value['Case']}, '{$value['Name']}', '{$value['Document']}', '{$value['Date']}')"; },
                    $values );
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table1 (Case, Name, Document, Date) VALUES ' . implode(',', $texts);
```

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to reuse the name multiple times while the document and date may change for that person. So you really only want to insert records for 2 people, but they have multiple documents to insert. You SQL isn't really normalized and there is probably a better way to do this but to avoid confusion here's how you can get it done right now.

```
$values = array($case, $name, $document, $date)

INSERT INTO table1 (case, name, document, date) VALUES (implode(", ", $values);
```

The array of values can be repeated as many times as you want, but that's what the first record would look like. You would have it in the same order it will be inserted in with your MySQL insert statement and then the next 4 items in the array would be the 2nd insert, the next 4 would be the 3rd, etc.

You will have to repeat the case and name with each of these though, so a very rough example of the array might look like this:

```
$values = array($case0, $name0, $document0, $date0, $case1, $name1, $document1, $date1)
```

I would make use of array_push() though and push each of those items in with each loop to build the array.

Hope this helps. When you start using mysqli and start getting into OOP you can do this differently in an easier way. For now though, this should get the job done.

Comment: The problem here is that the document and date varies on different person. I am trying to store a person/client with many documents and different deadline.

Comment: Yes, you would have to re-insert the person and case for each row. The SQL I gave you will produce a table like the one you describe. However as I said, it's really not the right way of approaching this problem, you should have a person table where you are linking to their primary key instead of just inserting the person's name for every record.